# How to minimize one argument of a function using Scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, minimize

I have the following function

```
def fun(X, alpha, y):
    #some stuff
    return J, gradient
```

And I am trying to minimze alpha with this, but nothing happens.

```
optimized_alpha = sp.optimize.minimize(lambda t: fun(X, t, y), alpha, method="Newton-CG", jac=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `functools.partial` to turn your function to partial function with only one argument. In order to make it work with `scipy.optimize.minimize` you will need to keep the variable argument at the last position:

```
def fun(X, y, alpha):
    #some stuff
    return J, gradient
```

then:

```
from functools import partial

optfunc = partial(func, X, y)
optimized_alpha = sp.optimize.minimize(optfunc, alpha, method="Newton-CG", jac=True)
```